# Refresh LWC Component after clicking Button

Tags: lightning-web-components

Can Anyone plese help me out to resolve the issue,By using HTMl table i displayed related record for Account and place a button to delete each record after deleting am unable to redirect ,if give manual refresh then only am get , same issue for creating a record also
****HTML:****

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="AccountFieldSet" icon-name="custom:custom63">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <template if:true={account}>
                <div class="slds-box slds-box_x-small">
                    <p>Name: {account.Name}</p>
                    <p>Industry: {account.Industry}</p>
                    <p>Description: {account.Description}</p>
                </div>
            </template>
        </div>
        </br> 
        <!-- <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <lightning-datatable
                key-field="id"
                data={contact}
                columns={columns} 
                draft-values={draftValues}>
            </lightning-datatable>
        </div>    --> 
        <div class="slds-p-around--medium">
            <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered" aria-labelledby="element-with-table-label other-element-with-table-label">
                <thead> 
                    <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
                        <th class="" scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="ID">ID</div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="" scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Name">Name</div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <template for:each={relatedrecord} for:item="rObj" for:index="index">
                        <tr class="slds-hint-parent" key={rObj.Id}>
                            <td>
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Id">{rObj.Id}</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Id">{rObj.Name}</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Id">
                                    <!--    <lightning-button variant="Destructive" data-id={rObj.Id} title="Destructive action" label="Delete" class="slds-button slds-button_destructive"  onclick={handleDelete}></lightning-button>
                              -->
                                    <lightning-button  icon-name="utility:delete"   value={rObj.Id}   onclick={handleDelete}></lightning-button>
                                </div>   
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </template>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <lightning-button icon-name="utility:add" label="Add" variant="brand" onclick={handleInputSearch} ></lightning-button>
            <template if:true={boolVisible}>
                <lightning-input   label="Name" placeholder="type here.."></lightning-input>
                <lightning-button  label="Save" variant="brand" onclick={handleCreateRecord} ></lightning-button>
            </template>
        </div> 
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**Js:**

```javascript
import { LightningElement,track,api,wire } from 'lwc';
import getAccountList from '@salesforce/apex/GetAccountFieldSetValuesForLwc.getAccountList';
import getsrelatedrecordstoAccount from '@salesforce/apex/GetAccountFieldSetValuesForLwc.getsrelatedrecordstoAccount';
import geRelatedRecordtoDelete from '@salesforce/apex/GetAccountFieldSetValuesForLwc.geRelatedRecordtoDelete';
import getRecordsToCreate from '@salesforce/apex/GetAccountFieldSetValuesForLwc.getRecordsToCreate';
import { updateRecord  } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import {ShowToastEvent} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import {refreshApex} from '@salesforce/apex';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class FieldSetComponent extends LightningElement {
    @track account;
    @track relatedrecord = [];
    @track error;
    @api recordId;
    @track recid;
    @track boolVisible = false;
    @track recName; ;
   
    /* @track columns=[
        {label:'Last Name', fieldName:'LastName' , type:'text',editable: true} ,
        {label:'Account Name', fieldName:'AccountName' , type:'Picklist',editable: true} 
    ] */
   
    @wire(getAccountList, { accid: '$recordId' })
    Account({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.account = data;
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.accs = undefined;
        }
    }
   
    @wire(getsrelatedrecordstoAccount,{accid: '$recordId'})
    relatedrec({error,data}){
        if (data) {
            this.relatedrecord = data;
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.relatedrecord = undefined;
        }
    }

    handleDelete(event){
        alert('handleclick');
        //recid = event.target.dataset.id;
        this.recid = event.target.value;
        console.log('recordId'+this.recid);
        alert('recid==='+this.recid);
        geRelatedRecordtoDelete({rId:this.recid})
        .then((result) => {
            const toastEvent = new ShowToastEvent({
                title:'Success!',
                message:'Record deleted successfully',
                variant:'success'
            });
            this.dispatchEvent(toastEvent);
            if(result){
                this.relatedrecords = result;
                console.log('relatedrecords after delete'+relatedrecords);
            }
            //return refreshApex(this.relatedrecords);
        }).catch((err) => {
            this.error = err;
        });
     }
    
     handleInputSearch(){
         this.boolVisible = true;
     }
   
    ///handleInputChange(event){
    //    this.recName = event.detail.value;
    //    console.log('recName=='+recName);
    //    alert('RecName=='+this.recName);
    // }
   
    handleCreateRecord(){
        this.recName = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input').value;
        alert('RecName=='+this.recName);
        alert(' this.recordId=='+ this.recordId);
        getRecordsToCreate({aid : this.recordId,rname :this.recName})
         
    /*  .then((result) => {
            this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({ 
                type: 'standard__recordPage', 
                attributes: { recordId: this.recordId, objectApiName: 'Account', actionName: 'view' },
            }); 
            //  updateRecord({ fields: { Id: this.recordId }})
            if(result == true){
                const toastEvent = new ShowToastEvent({
                    title:'Success!',
                    message:'Record Created successfully '+result,
                    variant:'success'
                });
                this.dispatchEvent(toastEvent);
            } 
        }).catch((err) => {    
        }); */
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```apex
public class GetAccountFieldSetValuesForLwc {
    public static List<Schema.FieldSetMember> getFields() {
        return SObjectType.Account.FieldSets.AccountField.getFields();
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Account getAccountList(id accid) {
        String query = 'SELECT ';
        for(Schema.FieldSetMember fs : GetAccountFieldSetValuesForLwc.getFields()) {
            query += fs.getFieldPath() + ', ';
        }
        query += 'Id FROM Account WHERE ID=\''+accid+'\'';
        System.debug(query);
        return Database.query(query);
    }

     @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
     public static list<Related_Record__c> getsrelatedrecordstoAccount(list<Id> accid){
         // idvalue = '%'+ accid +'%';
         System.debug('accountid'+accid);
         list<Related_Record__c> relatedlist = \[select id,Name from Related_Record__c where Account__c IN:accid\];
         System.debug('relatedlist=='+relatedlist);
         return relatedlist; 
    } 
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static list<Related_Record__c>  geRelatedRecordtoDelete(Id rId){
        ID recordid = rId;
        System.debug('recordid--------->>'+recordid);
        List<Related_Record__c> recordstodelete = \[select id,Name from Related_Record__c where ID =:recordid\];
        System.debug('relatedlist=='+recordstodelete);
        delete recordstodelete; 
        List<Related_Record__c> relatedlist = \[select id,Name from Related_Record__c where ID =:recordid\];
        return relatedlist; 
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static ID getRecordsToCreate(String aid,string rname){
        System.debug('aid=='+aid);
        System.debug('rrname=='+rname);
        Related_Record__c  rr = new Related_Record__c(Account__c = aid );
        rr.Name= rname;
        insert rr;
        return rr.ID;
    } 
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Store the result in a variable and then use that to refresh.

```
 @track relatedRecordResult;
    @wire(getsrelatedrecordstoAccount,{accid: '$recordId'})
            relatedrec(result){
                this.relatedRecordResult = result;
                if (result.data) {
                    this.relatedrecord = result.data;
                    this.error = undefined;
                } else if (result.error) {
                    this.error = error;
                    this.relatedrecord = undefined;
                }
            }
```

And refresh this as

```
 refreshApex(this.relatedRecordResult)
```

Comment: Thank you, I Used it but didn't worked

Comment: Can you paste the updated code

Answer (score 1):

first your need to declare your accout variable as follows before the wire method:

```
_accounts; 
get accounts(){
  return this._accounts;
}
set accounts(value){
  this._accounts = value; 
}
```

then inside your delete function, you need to call your apex method again like so :

```
 getAccountList({accid : this.recordId}).then(res =>{
    this.accounts = res; 
  }).catch(error=>{
    console.log(error);
  })
```

it will automatically update the view. this is the best way to refresh the view without having to refresh the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { LightningElement,track,api,wire } from 'lwc';
import getAccountList from '@salesforce/apex/GetAccountFieldSetValuesForLwc.getAccountList';
import getsrelatedrecordstoAccount from '@salesforce/apex/GetAccountFieldSetValuesForLwc.getsrelatedrecordstoAccount';
import geRelatedRecordtoDelete from '@salesforce/apex/GetAccountFieldSetValuesForLwc.geRelatedRecordtoDelete';
import getRecordsToCreate from '@salesforce/apex/GetAccountFieldSetValuesForLwc.getRecordsToCreate';
import { updateRecord  } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import {ShowToastEvent} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import {refreshApex} from '@salesforce/apex';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class FieldSetComponent extends LightningElement {
    @track account;
    @track relatedrecord = [];
    @track relatedRecordResult;
    @track error;
    @api recordId;
    @track recid;
    @track boolVisible = false;
    @track recName; 
    @track isLoading = false;
   
    /* @track columns=[
    {label:'Last Name', fieldName:'LastName' , type:'text',editable: true} ,
    {label:'Account Name', fieldName:'AccountName' , type:'Picklist',editable: true} 
] */
   
    @wire(getAccountList, { accid: '$recordId' })
    Account({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.account = data;
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.accs = undefined;
        }
    }
   
    @wire(getsrelatedrecordstoAccount,{accid: '$recordId'})

    relatedrec(result){
                this.relatedRecordResult = result;
                if (result.data) {
                    this.relatedrecord =  this.relatedRecordResult.data;
                    this.error = undefined;
                } else if (result.error) {
                    this.error = error;
                    this.relatedrecord = undefined;
                }
            }

    handleDelete(event){
        alert('handleclick');
          //recid = event.target.dataset.id;
          this.recid = event.target.value;
        // const tr = event.target.closest("tr");
        //tr.classList.add('hide');
        //  eval("$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();");
          
         alert('recid==='+this.recid);
         this.handleIsLoading(true);
        geRelatedRecordtoDelete({rId:this.recid})
        .then((result) => {
              updateRecord({ fields: { Id: this.recid }})
            const toastEvent = new ShowToastEvent({
                title:'Success!',
                message:'Record deleted successfully',
                variant:'success'
              });
              this.dispatchEvent(toastEvent);
              this.updateRecordView();
              if(result){
                  this.relatedrecords = result;
                  console.log('relatedrecords after delete'+relatedrecords);
              }
             //updateRecord({ fields: { Id: this.recordId }})
            //return refreshApex(this.relatedRecordResult);
         
        }).catch((err) => {
            this.error = err;
        }).finally(()=>{
            this.handleIsLoading(false);
        });

       /* geRelatedRecordtoDelete({rId:this.recid})
        .then(result => {
                eval("$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();");
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('error: ', error);
            }); */
    
    }
    
   
    handleInputSearch(){
        this.boolVisible = true;
    }
   ///handleInputChange(event){
     //   this.recName = event.detail.value;
      //  console.log('recName=='+recName);
       // alert('RecName=='+this.recName);
  // }
   
   handleCreateRecord(){
        this.recName = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input').value;
       
        alert('RecName=='+this.recName);
        alert(' this.recordId=='+ this.recordId);
        getRecordsToCreate({aid : this.recordId,rname :this.recName})
         return refreshApex(this.relatedRecordResult);
        /* .then((result) => {
             
               this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({ 
              type: 'standard__recordPage', 
              attributes: { recordId: this.recordId, objectApiName: 'Account', actionName: 'view' },
           }); 
           //  updateRecord({ fields: { Id: this.recordId }})
            if(result == true){
                 const toastEvent = new ShowToastEvent({
                title:'Success!',
                message:'Record Created successfully '+result,
                variant:'success'
              });
              this.dispatchEvent(toastEvent);

             } 
        }).catch((err) => {
            
        }); */
       
   }
   handleIsLoading(isLoading) {
        this.isLoading = isLoading;
    }
     updateRecordView() {
       setTimeout(() => {
            eval("$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();");
       }, 1000); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the answer for your own question or should it be an edit to initial question? I suggest to clarify this and to format the code on the answer.